# Not getting response in time when using geo.find() in node.js

Tags: node.js, geolocation, google-geolocation

I have tried to get the response from below code:-

```
  let latlongdata;
  if (userInfo.address != "" && userInfo.country != "") {
    let add = userInfo.address + "," + userInfo.country;
    geo.find(add, function(err, res) {
      latlongdata = res[0].location.lat;
      console.log("Inside output", res[0].location.lat); // Got response
    });
    console.log("Outside output", getletlong); // No response
  }
}
```

On consoling "Inside output" I got response,
On consoling "Outside output" I got no response

I also tried using async await, below is the code:-

```
if (userInfo.address != "" && userInfo.country != "") {
  add = userInfo.address + "," + userInfo.country;
  [err, data] = await to(geo.find(add));

  console.log("output", data);
  console.log("error", err);
}
```

Finally I got the response when I used setTimeOut()

```
let latlongdata;
if (userInfo.address != "" && userInfo.country != "") {
  add = userInfo.address + "," + userInfo.country;
  geo.find(add, function(err, res) {
    if (res) {
      userInfo.latitude = res[0].location.lat;
    }
  });
}
userInfo.role_id = 2;
setTimeout(async () => {
  [err, user] = await to(User.create(userInfo));
}, 300);
```

But I think this is not the right way, also I think this will not work for me in every case, please can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong in the first two approaches.

I used.:- "google-geocoder": "^0.2.1"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us the geolocation package you use. In other words, please show the code creating the `geo` object you use in your code.

Comment: @O.Jones I used "google-geocoder": "^0.2.1" for this

Answer (score 0):

I have done some R&D and find the below solution

```
let add = userInfo.address + "," + userInfo.country;
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  geo.find(
    "India",
    (err, res) => {
      if (res) {
        resolve(res);
      }
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    },
    err => {
      reject(err);
    }
  );
});
```